# Silent push notification in android

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com, silent

I've been used urban airship for notification and it's working. 
Now client's requirement has been, he want to update a specific data (ie: current location) for client once any silent notification(no status bar notification) received. Could any one help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Please show us the current code you are using for displaying push notifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a couple of ways to send a silent notification to android devices.  If you are using the built in notification builders, the notification will return null when the alert is empty.  If you are using a custom one, just make sure its returning null when the alert is empty.

Then, send a notification with an empty alert.  It will still come through on the push broadcast receiver.